# What code should I write to change the color of the table to green?

Tags: html, css, colors, header

How can I change the color of the table from gray to black? I already tried `background-color: green` but but it wont affect the heading background of the table.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .table-fixed thead {
        width: 97%;
    }
    .table-fixed tbody {
        height: 230px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
        display: block;
    }
    .table-fixed tbody td, .table-fixed thead > tr> th {
        float: left;
        border-bottom-

width: 0;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h4>
                     Fixed Header Scrolling Table 
                 </h4>

            </div>
            <table class="table table-fixed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-xs-2">#</th>
                        <th class="col-xs-8">Name</th>
                        <th class="col-xs-2">Points</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">1</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-8">Mike Adams</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">23</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">2</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-8">Holly Galivan</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">44</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">3</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-8">Mary Shea</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">86</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">4</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-8">Jim Adams</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">23</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">5</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-8">Henry Galivan</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">44</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">5</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-8">Henry Galivan</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">44</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the background against just the .table-fixed class works fine:

```
.table-fixed {
    background-color: green;
}
```

I think you may have been setting it for just the tbody element, if the header wasn't being affected.

To set the entire panel's background colour, you could try setting a new class on the panel DIV, and then set the colour of this in css.

```
<style>
    .panel-green { background-color: green; }
</style>

<div class="panel panel-default panel-green">
    ....
</div>
```

Or explicitly set the background on the panel:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color: green">
    ....
</div>
```

Comment: i mean the Fixed Header Scrolling Table  background? thank you.. =)

Comment: I put it in CSS style sheet the whole table got affected with the green

Comment: I added another couple of examples. You could also replace `panel-default` with `panel-success` which would give you a standard green heading, assuming those are Bootstrap panels.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try:
edit: overlooked `th` elements

```
table thead th{
      background:green;
}
```

Here is [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o10oL2pu/)

Comment: if it worked, you can mark it as an answer to confirm :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.table header{
    background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the table header color,table header text color, table background color.

I add some css code in your code.I commented that code

```css
.table{
     background-color: green;/* done by me */
    
} 


.table-fixed thead {
        width: 97%;
    background-color: red;/* done by me */
    color: white;/* done by me */
    }
    .table-fixed thead {
        width: 97%;
    }
    .table-fixed tbody {
        height: 230px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
       / display: block;
    }
    .table-fixed tbody td, .table-fixed thead > tr> th {
        float: left;
        border-bottom-

width: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h4>
                     Fixed Header Scrolling Table 
                 </h4>

            </div>
            <table class="table table-fixed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-xs-2">#</th>
                        <th class="col-xs-8">Name</th>
                        <th class="col-xs-2">Points</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">1</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-8">Mike Adams</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">23</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">2</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-8">Holly Galivan</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">44</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">3</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-8">Mary Shea</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">86</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">4</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-8">Jim Adams</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">23</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">5</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-8">Henry Galivan</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">44</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">5</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-8">Henry Galivan</td>
                        <td class="col-xs-2">44</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much.. I cant vote it.. 15 reputation..  Btw thanks!